# Android Simple Horizontal RecyclerView very slow and not smooth

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement Horizontal Recycler View but its not scrolling smooth at all.

tried all of the following solution i found in google but none of them worked:

```
popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
setHasStableIds(true);
```

I've also tried using `Picasso/Glide` and even not loading the image at all, but it still doesn't scroll smoothly.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView popularCategoriesRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter popularCategoriesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RootCategory demoCategory = CreateDemoModelService.create();

        popularCategoriesRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.popular_categories_recycler_view);
        popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
        popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,true);
            popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        popularCategoriesAdapter = new FavoriteCategoryAdapter(demoCategory.getFavoriteCategories());
        popularCategoriesRecyclerView.setAdapter(popularCategoriesAdapter);
    }
}
```

and the adapter:

```
public class FavoriteCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private List<Category> categories;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView iv;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.adapter_favorite_category_tv);
            iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.adapter_favorite_category_iv);
        }
    }

    public FavoriteCategoryAdapter(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_popular_category,parent,false);
        return new FavoriteCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Category category = categories.get(position);
        FavoriteCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (FavoriteCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder) holder;

        if (viewHolder.tv.getText() != null && viewHolder.tv.getText().equals(category.getName()))
            return;

        Context context = viewHolder.iv.getContext();
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(category.getIconName() + "_popular", "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());

        Picasso.with(context).load(resourceId).fit().centerCrop().into(viewHolder.iv);

        viewHolder.tv.setText(category.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categories.size();
    }
}
```

adapter_category.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/adapter_popular_category_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_favorite_category_iv"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_favorite_category_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/adapter_popular_category_tv_bg"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_popular"
            android:textColor="#75A735"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/popular_categories_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: show recyclerview  xml code also

Comment: added xml as well

Comment: have you tried CustomRecyclerView?

Comment: try with, remove extara LinearLayout from xml and change from true to false in layout manager, remove all cache size parameter and stable ids in both activity and adapter.

Comment: finally add this method in adapter 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

Comment: @DivyeshPatel tried it, still doesn't work..

Comment: @NareshRavva why do i need CustomRecyclerView? it's pretty simple what I'm trying to do here i think..

Comment: then your onbindviewholder is creating problems

Comment: write just Category category = categories.get(position);   holder.tv.setText(category.getName());

Comment: @DivyeshPatel did that too, still not smooth..

Comment: remove static from ViewHolder class and remove adapter_popular_category_bg from layout background

Comment: @ShaiAlkoby May be you've loading very heavy data it takes time to get data if its not hope this will help you: mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found out what was the problem.

My Activity had a background image that apparently was too big (found it because it wasn't showing on some devices), so after i reduced the resolution of the background image, everything works smoothly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend you adapter with your own ViewHolder.

```
class FavoriteCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoriteCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

You will also need to change return type of adapter function *onCreateViewHolder* and parameter type of holder in function *onBindViewHolder*

```
public void onBindViewHolder(FavoriteCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)

public FavoriteCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
```

Comment: better, still not as smooth as i would expect

Answer (score 0):

This line: `final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(category.getIconName() +"_popular", "drawable",context.getPackageName());` is pretty expensive, the official documentation says:

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name

Now in your case, I guess you don't have a choice since you want to dynamically find the right image. What you could do is find all the resources identifiers in the adapter's constructor and store these in a `Map`.

Hope this helps.